# Internet Mobile data for only a specific application

Tags: networking, whatsapp

Some mobile providers around the world offer stuff like WhatsApp bundle where the user has data for the app which require an Internet connection but not for browsing or any other app. I need to know how this is implemented on a networking level? Why the browser can't access the data? Are the packets exchanged different from packets used in a regular mobile

Answer (score 0):

They probably count the data depending on what domain name you're communicating with, this is typically implemented on a high level with software.